# How to set a static resource as content property (default content)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I have a trigger action implementation for prism's `InteractionRequestTrigger` which looks something like this:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding MyRequest}" >
    <infInt:PopupWindowAction>...
    </infInt:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Now I wanted to extract the `PopupWindowAction` into a static resource so it looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <infInt:PopupWindowAction x:Key="Foo" >
      ...
    </infInt:PopupWindowAction>
</Window.Resources>

<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding MyRequest}" >
   --- use the resource Foo ---
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

How can I use the Static Resource with the key Foo in there?

By reflecting on the `InteractionRequestTrigger` I found out that the ContentProperty for it is set in `System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase` to `[ContentProperty("Actions")]`

but since it has only a getter, I cannot use Actions as parameter to set foo:

```
  <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger Actions="{StaticResource Foo}" SourceObject="{Binding MyRequest}" />
```

> Error 1   The property "Actions" does not have an accessible setter.
>   Error 3   'Actions' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.

How can I use `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Use the [StaticResourceExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.staticresourceextension(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding MyRequest}">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Foo"/>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: It is annoying that it works perfectly during runtime but the designer complains that it requires a `TriggerCollection` but got a `Trigger`, however the `StaticResource` does its job, thank you.